# How to get a bot react to its own embed?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to figure out how the bot will react to an embed, more specifically, its own. I have gotten to the step where I have made the bot display an embed (after the user writes the command !start) but it does not react it with the  emoji. All the help is appreciated!

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const guild = new Discord.Guild();
const token = 'redacted';
const p1 = 'Player 1';

const serve = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Time to serve!')
    .setDescription(p1 + ' react below to take the serve')
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/764193096060764211.png?v=1');


bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})





bot.on('message', message =>{
    
    if(message.content === "!start"){
        message.channel.send(serve);
    
    }

    
    if (message.content === serve ){
        embedMessage.react("");
        
    }
    
})  



bot.login(token);
```

Comment: I have also tried troubleshooting this and added this:
bot.on('embed', Discord.MessageEmbed => {

 if (embed.content === serve) {
  
  embed.react("")
 }
})

But however there is a red underline at the '=>' saying a comma is expected

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to let the bot react to it's own messages.

Simply send the message, or embed, and `.then()` react to it . The reason we need `.then()` here is because we need to wait for the message to actually be sent, otherwise we might run into an error.

```
message.channel.send(serve).then(m => {
  m.react("");
})
```

Comment: However when I do this, the embed goes on a loop forever!

Comment: Well, you need to put some logic before that. You know, check if the author is a bot, make sure that it only reacts to certain messages. That sort of thing.